# AWS Lambda. Invoke with delay

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, task-queue, amazon-cloudwatch

I need to build  "tasks scheduler" with Amazon tools. Main problem that i need execute task once with huge delay (it may be a few hours or few weeks).

I try to research how to build it with CloudWatch and Lambda function. As i understand - i need to use separate rule for one timeout execution. 
But AWS allow me only 100 rules/account.

Probably i'm going wrong way and this tools not intended for my task.

Also i tried SQS, but it did't allow me to set timeout more than 15 minutes. The simplest way - use own mircoservice with crone, but i hope that it is possible to do it in cloud )

May be someone has the same issue and can share with me thoughts about the implementation of this?

Comment: Are you trying to accomplish this without using an EC2 instance?

Answer (score 2):

CloudWatch rules should work and you can use a cron expression for the event schedule.

Comment: Yes. ClouWatch works. But AWS set limit to 100 rules. 
In my case i can take 10 000 delayed events.

Comment: You can [request a limit increase](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html).

"`Before requesting a limit increase, examine your rules. You may have multiple rules each matching to very specific events. Consider broadening their scope by using fewer identifiers in your Events and Event Patterns. In addition, a rule can invoke several targets each time it matches an event. Consider adding more targets to your rules.`"

Comment: If you have 10,000 scheduled events, you should use a dedicated scheduler as per @tom's suggestions above.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to use [disque](https://github.com/antirez/disque) for delaying message/retry and [apscheduler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/APScheduler) (python) for scheduling your tasks.

You can use disque as a cluster also.

You can put these two inside an ec2-machine depending on your use-case.

Let me know, if you need any help!

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to use [AWS Step Functions Wait State](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-wait-state.html) for this. I haven't used it myself but it seems like you can define a state machine where the result of a lamdba function can be used to determine how long to wait until the next step function.

Alternatively, my API https://posthook.io is able to make HTTP POST requests to defined endpoints at specific times.

Answer (score 1):

As someone pointed out earlier you can use the AWS step function, A sample definition that will delay lambda execution for the specified time period. You can trigger this step function from cloud watch event rules targets or event bridge

```
{
  "Comment": "An example of the Amazon States Language using wait states",
  "StartAt": "wait_using_seconds",
  "States": {
    "wait_using_seconds": {
      "Type": "Wait",
      "Seconds": 450, // time to delay
      "Next": "FinalState"
    },
    "FinalState": {
     "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:<region>:<account-name>:function:<function-name>",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have any flexibility to use a cloud provider other than AWS, the Google Cloud Tasks API can provide the functionality you're looking for. There's a simple demonstration web service built using this API at https://delayedrequest.com