# Delay Lambda execution over specific data

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, scheduling, serverless

I am trying to come up with a way to have pieces of data processed at specific time intervals by invoking aws lambda every N hours.

For example, parse a page at specific url every 6 hours and store result in s3 bucket.
Have *many* (~100k) urls each processed that way.

Of course, you can have a VM that hosts some scheduler that would trigger lambdas, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44207586/4910910), but that breaks the "serverless" approach.

So, is there a way to do this using aws services only?

Things I tried that does not work:

- **SQS** can delay messages, but only for maximum of 15 min (I need hours) and there is no built-in integration between SQS and Lambda so you need to have some polling agent (lambda?) that would poll the qeueu all the time and send new messages to worker lambda, which again breaks the point of only executing at scheduled time;
- **CloudWatch Alarms** can send messages to SNS that triggers Lambda. You can have periodic lambda calls implemented like that by using [future metric timestamp](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/3mzxri/how_i_can_invoke_lambda_with_a_delay/cvke3io/), however alarm message cannot have a custom data (think url from example above) connected to it, so that does not work too;
- I could create **Lambda CloudWatch scheduled triggers** programmatically but they also cannot pass any data to Lambda.

The only way I could think of, is to have a dynamo DB table with "url" records, each with the timestamp of last "processing" and have periodic lambda that would query the table and send "old" records as jobs to another "worker" lambda (directly or via SNS).
That would work, however you still need to have a "polling" lambda, which could become a bottleneck as number of items to process grows.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

100k jobs every 6 hours, doesn't sound like a great use case for Serverless IMO. Personally, I would set up a CloudWatch event with a relevant cron expression that triggered a Lambda to start an EC2 instance that processed all the URLs (stored in DynamoDB) and script the EC2 instance to shutdown after processing the last url.

But that's not what you asked.

You could set up a CloudWatch event with a relevant cron expression that spawns a lambda (orchestrator) reads the urls from DynamoDB or even an S3 file then invokes a second lambda (worker) for each url to actually parse the pages.

Using this pattern you will start hitting concurrency issues at 1000 lambdas (1 orchestrator & 999 workers), less if you have other lambdas running in the same region. You can ask AWS to increase this limit, but I don't know under what scenarios they will do this, or how high they will increase the limit.

From here you have three choices.

1. Split out the payload to each worker lambda so each instance receives multiple urls to process.
2. Add an another column to your list of urls and group urls with this column (e.g. first 500 are marked with a 1, second 500 are marked with a 2, etc). Then your orchestrator lambda could take urls off the list in batches. This would require you to run the CloudWatch event at a greater frequency and manage the state so the orchestrator lambda when invoked knows which is the next batch (I've done this at a smaller scale just storing a variable in a S2 file).
3. Would be to use some combination of options 1 and 2.

Comment: Sory if this was not clear from original question, but I did not mean to have all ~100k urls processed at the same time. Urls are added over time, each having its own schedule.

E.g. url #1 added at 12:00 and will be processed at 20:00 next time. Url #2 added at 12:30 and will be processed next at 20:30 etc. This also allows setting different intervals on urls, e.g. it could be that some domain should be processed every 6 hours while the other domain needs 3 hours rate. This is why I was thinking that the load would spread evenly over time, with worker lambdas spinning here and there.

Comment: @alexandr-sugak In that case, I can't see any other way to do this without a polling lambda as you mentioned yourself in your question. I would query why you think this would become a bottleneck though. With the numbers your talking about, I don't think it would be unreasonable to poll every 5 minutes.

Comment: an ideal solution, as I see it, would be a "delayed" queue where each message has configured delay. So the workflow would be -> read new "job" message from queue -> process it and save results -> put new message on queue with delay of, say, 6 hrs (note - Azure Storage Queues support such delays, while SQS does not). This way you need to only monitor one queue and scale its subscriptions. With polling lambda there are now 2 places to monitor - worker queue and polling lambda. I agree with you that it should not be a bottleneck though.

Comment: On a second thought though, having dynamo db table with all jobs schedule is a good thing and "delated queue" solution would probably be harder to maintain (e.g. handling dead letters and recovering from failures overall)

Comment: My thoughts were heading to having a lambda poll a database for times in the past, then have the lambda set the next time in the future. If you held the frequency in the database, you could add n hours onto the time it next needs to be processed. using DynamoDB for this would be a pain, as you would have to include the datetime as an index (so you could query for it), meaning you couldn't change the time, just add a new entry into the db, then delete the original entry.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like, it's fitting [Batch processing](https://aws.amazon.com/batch/) scenario with AWS lambda function as a job. It's serverless but obviously adds dependency on another AWS service.

In the same time, it has [dashboard](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-batch-run-batch-computing-jobs-on-aws/), processing status, retries and all perks from job scheduling service.

Comment: Thanks! Interesting, will take a look at batch processing scenario.